# Java exec() does not run busybox commands on android

Tags: java, android, exec, busybox

I wanted to run some shell commands through a java program for android. The app just takes in a command executes it on the shell and returns the result.

I used this  :

> Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(in); 
>      p.waitFor();
>
> BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
>
> String line=reader.readLine();
>
> output = line;
>
> while(line!=null) {
>
> ```
>    output = output +"\n"+ line;
>    //System.out.println(line);
> ```
>
> line=reader.readLine();
>
> }

"in" is the input from a text box.

1> I observed that  most of the commands that come as a part of android work for the above statement. But i installed busybox to get other linux commands too. But none of these commands are running. Every time it just returns a NULL result. I Installed busybox both into /system/xbin as well as /system/bin (after remounting the /system partition as read/write)

2> Secondly if I do ls on a particular location  like ls /sdcard, it takes /sdcard as the command. But ls -l works (just in case you feel the whitespace is causing a problem)

Please help me out

Comment: What is the content of `in` with a working command? What is the content of some busybox that does not work? Do you have some logcat of a non working exec?

Comment: For a non working exec - 

W/InputManagerService(   61): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406f2d28

Comment: in" will get any command that is imput. for ex - if i input ls, in = "ls". This will execute. What do you mean by content of busybox?